# What would be the time complexity for linked lists

Tags: algorithm, big-o

What would be the runtime complexity for a linked list with for loop. Based on my understanding it is 0(n). I am not sure if my answer is correct.

```html
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test1 {

 public static void main(String[] argv) {
  List<Integer> r;

  // Displays entire sequence for 1 child
  System.out.println("Sequence for 1 child");
  System.out.println(r = func1(1, 2, 1));
  // Displays the last person
  System.out.printf("The Winner is %d \n", r.get(r.size() - 1));
  System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

  // Displays entire sequence for 2 children
  System.out.println("Sequence for 2 children");
  System.out.println(r = func1(2, 2, 1));
  // Displays the last person
  System.out.printf("The Winner is %d \n", r.get(r.size() - 1));
  System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

  // Displays entire sequence for 3 children
  System.out.println("Sequence for 3 children");
  System.out.println(r = func1(3, 2, 1));
  // Displays the last person
  System.out.printf("The Winner is %d \n", r.get(r.size() - 1));
  System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

  // Displays entire sequence for 4 children
  System.out.println("Sequence for 4 children");
  System.out.println(r = func1(4, 2, 1));
  // Displays the last person
  System.out.printf("The Winner is %d \n", r.get(r.size() - 1));
  System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

  // Displays entire sequence for 5 children
  System.out.println("Sequence for 5 children");
  System.out.println(r = func1(5, 2, 1));
  // Displays the last person
  System.out.printf("The Winner is %d \n", r.get(r.size() - 1));
  System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

  // Displays entire sequence for 6 children
  System.out.println("Sequence for 6 children");
  System.out.println(r = func1(6, 2, 1));
  // Displays the last person
  System.out.printf("The Winner is %d \n", r.get(r.size() - 1));
  System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

  // Displays entire sequence for 7 children
  System.out.println("Sequence for 7 children");
  System.out.println(r = func1(7, 2, 1));
  // Displays the last person
  System.out.printf("The Winner is %d \n", r.get(r.size() - 1));
  System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

  // Displays entire sequence for 8 children
  System.out.println("Sequence for 8 children");
  System.out.println(r = func1(8, 2, 1));
  // Displays the last person
  System.out.printf("The Winner is %d \n", r.get(r.size() - 1));
  System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

 }

 // Remove N elements in equal steps starting at specific point
 public static List<Integer> func1(int N, int step, int start) {
  if (N < 1 || step < 1 || start < 1) {
   return null;
  }

  List<Integer> p = new LinkedList<Integer>();
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
   p.add(i + 1);

  }

  List<Integer> r = new LinkedList<Integer>();
  int i = (start - 2) % N;
  for (int j = N; j > 0; j--) {
   i = (i + step) % N--;
   r.add(p.remove(i--));
   // System.out.println(r);
  }

  return r;
 }

}
```

The output is as follows
Sequence for 1 child
[1]

### The Winner is 1

Sequence for 2 children
[2, 1]

### The Winner is 1

Sequence for 3 children
[2, 1, 3]

### The Winner is 3

Sequence for 4 children
[2, 4, 3, 1]

### The Winner is 1

Sequence for 5 children
[2, 4, 1, 5, 3]

### The Winner is 3

Sequence for 6 children
[2, 4, 6, 3, 1, 5]

### The Winner is 5

Sequence for 7 children
[2, 4, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7]

### The Winner is 7

Sequence for 8 children
[2, 4, 6, 8, 3, 7, 5, 1]

### The Winner is 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR:

Your first loop is `O(N)`, and the second is `O(N^2)`.

### (not so) Long explanation:

Your first loop is `O(N)` because you are accessing all elements in the list, and each `add` call is `O(1)`.

From Java's official documentation:

> public boolean `add(E e)` 
>   Appends the specified element to the end of this list.
>   This method is equivalent to `addLast(E)`.

If you had to use use `add(int index, E e)`, this would be `O(N^2)` because this function with 2 parameters has a time complexity of `O(N)` access, and access `N` times an `O(N)` function gives you `O(N^2)`. However, this is not your case.

On the other hand, your second loop is `O(N^2)`  because you are adding an element with an `O(1)` but you are also deleting an element using `delete(int index)` which takes `O(N)`. This methods takes `O(N)` because first, it search the node at the position you want to access, and then it removes the elements changing the pointer references. Remember that a LinkedList doesn't have a direct access, it has pointers and `O(1)` is only for operations that involves both the head and tail elements or using an iterator.